# UserID with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Enabled User ID on GA.
GTM is setup and using dataLayer to push userId

```
dataLayer.push({'userId': "fetch logged in user"})
```

Created DataLayer variable to fetch userId.
Created Universal Tag & adding userId field and dimension.
Tested userId tag from GTM preview.

But, I don't see userId in User Tracker report on GA. If I replace data layer variable with some constant then I can see those on GA.

Anyone knows what could be an issue?

[image]

Comment: why didn't you ask your question in the title...? you won't get anyone clicking on such vague title...

Answer (score 2):

Are you pushing the `userId` onto the dataLayer **before** the GTM container code? If not, then this would explain why it's not being picked up. Your tag has a trigger of All Pages. This means that tag will fire whenever the `gtm.js` event is pushed onto the dataLayer. So you need to make sure that the `userId` is available and ready on the dataLayer **before** the `gtm.js` event is pushed onto the dataLayer. Since it's the GTM container code that is responsible for pushing the `gtm.js` event onto the dataLayer, then you need to push the `userId` onto the dataLayer before the GTM container code executes.

To fix this, your final code should look something like this:

```
<script>

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({'userId': "fetch logged in user"});

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

</script>
```

Comment: you're saying all the right things, but what you didn't say is how we can achieve this. I'm trying to get my custom login event to fire before the container loaded event so I can see the user id in GA

Comment: Modified the answer to make the solution more clear